# Set profile level using rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, profile, rmongodb

Is there a way to issue the set profiling level command from R using rmongodb library?
The corresponding shell command is:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on review of [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/rmongodb.pdf) there is nothing related to `profiling` there. So I assume that it is not possible.

I suggest you to ask for a feature request on their [github](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb)